# Bibtex file content won't appear in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

Somehow I can't get through this problem.
I have made a `beamer` presentation. At the very end of it I would like to present the `.bib` file that I have created. Though I get no errors, I also can not get any content of this file to appear.

Here is the code of the last frame:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Literaturverzeichnis}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{bibliographie}
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you run `bibtex` on the file? See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any problems with your code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Literaturverzeichnis} 
\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha} 
\bibliography{bibliographie} 
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

You have to compile the file multiple times:

- `pdflatex`
- `bibtex`
- `pdflatex`
- `pdflatex`

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from your post, and it works just fine.

First, you must run the pdflatex command to create a PDF, even if nothing appears on the last frame.

Then, run the bibtex command to load the **bibliographie.bib** file, and then the pdflatex command again.

After that, the references in **bibliographie.bib** will appear in the last frame.